# sound lib python

Tags: python

im looking for a sound lib for python that can tall me per frame the volume of a sound file

or a software that can do a noise gate,preferd command line software

thanx!!

Answer (score 3):

The [snack](http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/) library can do it. In particular, this library support WAV, AU, AIFF, MP3, CSL, SD, SMP, and NIST/Sphere files. It can play the sound, do power spectrum analysis and filtering.

Comment: its a very good tool but its not fit for me...can you recommend anntuer tool?

Comment: I don't know. You need to be more specific on what you need if you want help.

Answer (score 3):

Python has a built-in [wave module](http://docs.python.org/library/wave.html)

```
import wave
import struct
import numpy

# read in the data string   
fin = wave.open("input.wav", "rb")
data_string = fin.readframes(fin.getnframes())
wav_params = fin.getparams()
fin.close()

# convert to volume
unpacked = struct.unpack("%dB"%(len(data_string)), data_string)
unpacked = [x**2 for x in unpacked]
# here's the volume
volume = [20 * numpy.log10(numpy.sqrt(i)) for i in unpacked]

noise_level = 40 # 'noise' level  

# filter out values below limit
outstring = ""
for i in range(len(data_string)):
    if volume[i] > noise_level:
        outstring += data_string[i]
    else:
        outstring += "\0"

# write result to new file
fout = wave.open("output.wav", "wb")
fout.setparams(wav_params)
fout.writeframes(outstring)
fout.close()
```

First-pass attempt.. needs to be optimised for files of any significant size. Hat-tip to [this blog post](http://shriphani.com/blog/2009/05/26/wav-files-spring-semester-research-hopes-ip/)

Answer (score 0):

The [pyo](https://code.google.com/p/pyo/) library is full of very useful sound manipulation and synthesis tools.

```
from pyo import *

s = Server().boot()
s.start()
sf = SfPlayer('input.aif', speed=[1,.5], loop=True)
gt = Gate(sf, thresh=-24, risetime=0.005, falltime=0.01, lookahead=5, mul=.4).out()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, correct me if I am wrong, but if you need volume per frame means resolution of each frame will go in microseconds.

For example , a typical audio file has 44,100 frame rate  which means 44,100 frames per sec ( or 1000 ms), that puts each frame processing in about 22.67 microseconds. Which is very fine for any application. Also, Audio is a compression wave that needs a set of samples to be analyzed to get its attribute such as frequency, power etc.

Anyway, if you want chunk resolution of 1ms, [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown) module may be utilized for this purpose.
Not sure if  this is whats needed.

## Sample Code

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub import utils

chunksize = 1 #ms

fname = "C:\\PATH_TO_THE_FILE\\myAudio.wav"
mysong = AudioSegment.from_wav(fname)
myAudioChunks = utils.make_chunks(mysong,chunksize)
#print "myAudioChunks =", myAudioChunks

for audioChunks in myAudioChunks:    
    loudness = audioChunks.dBFS
    print " loudness in dBFS =", loudness
```

Above will give loudness in DBFS, if you want loudness in different parameters here are couple of examples.

1)  To get loudness in RMS

replace `loudness = audioChunks.dBFS`  with `loudness = audioChunks.rms`

2) To get maximum loudness in sample [ i.e. highest amplitude in any sample set ]

replace  `loudness = audioChunks.dBFS`  with  `loudness = audioChunks.max`